# React Router: Redirect logged in users to account if direct visit

Tags: reactjs, meteor, react-router

I'd like logged in users who visit my home page by typing the url directly to be re-routed to their account, however I want them to be able to visit the homepage if they come from inside the app, what's the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is to check the previous page that the user was on.  So in your in your componentWillMount on your homepage React component, insert something like this:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
...
...
componentWillMount() {
  if (Meteor.userId()) {
    const referrer = document.referrer;
    if (!referrer.includes('yoururl')) { // you can use Meteor.absoluteUrl() or example.com
      browserHistory.push('/dashboard') // push whatever page you want
    }
  }
}
```

This will check to see if a user exists and where they came from.  If the user exists and did not come from your site, they will go straight to `/dashboard`.  Otherwise, the page will load as normal.